# Product Search Restiction for specific customer

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How can we write the impex for Product Search Restriction for specific customer?

I have tried with below impex but it still shows customer the product.

```
INSERT_UPDATE Customer;originalUid[unique=true];uid[unique=true];title(code);name;description;sessionLanguage(isocode);sessionCurrency(isocode);groups(uid);password[default=$defaultPassword]
;dummyUser@gmail.com;dummyUser@gmail.com;;dummy user;dummy user;en;EUR;customergroup;test1234


INSERT_UPDATE UserGroup;uid[unique=true] ;groups(uid)  ;members(uid);
;ph-testuser;customergroup;dummyUser@gmail.com;

INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true]      ;name[lang=en]         ;query                     ;principal(UID);restrictedType(code);active;generate
                           ;testcustomer_visibility;User Group Restriction;{code}   IN ('1694502');dummyUser@gmail.com ;Product             ;true  ;true
```

Comment: Can the customer see it also on product detail page or only on category page/search page?

Comment: Customer not able to Add To Cart/Placed the order function if product is restricted for customer so i want to restrict every where to visible for customer

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Is it possible to visit the product details page of the product with the code 1694502?